# Angular12: JSPDF not working in higher environment with micro frontend application

Tags: angular, jspdf, angular12, micro-frontend

I was using JSPDF in my application. I was able to download the pdf in local when running the micro frontend application on standalone. but when i ran the build for the micro frontend i was facing issue when i download the PDF (getting error in the console).

Note: my micro frontend application is build independently and reference it to main application using the main.js file.

Version i am using `"jspdf": "^2.5.1"`

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [550, 240]);

doc.html(exportToPdf, {
  callback: function (doc) {
    doc.save(selectedOptionName);
  },
  x: 15,
  y: 15,
  windowWidth: 650,
  width: 170
});
```

angular.json

```
  "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js"
            ],
```

I have added the min.js to scripts in angular.json as well but facing below error in the console when downloading pdf
[image]

node modules:
[image]